# Is it good practice to read a channel as condition for if statement?

Tags: go

I've seen a few examples with this:

```
type data struct {
    request chan string
    response chan bool
}
```

and used like this:

```
db := &data{make(chan string), make(chan bool)}
if db.request<- "boo"; !<-db.response {
    do something ...
}
```

Does "polling" from the response channel not block ? Also won't the if condition be sometimes evaluated before the other end of the channel can respond ? Is this pattern used anywhere in the standard libraries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not polling anything, and yes the channel receive operation can always block.

`<-db.response` is a normal receive operation. The `db.response` chan must be a `chan bool`, and the `!` is the logical "not" unary operator.

Comment: I'm referring to the expression itself, not the statement that precedes it.

Comment: @Sridhar: I'm failing to see what your question is, since it's just an expression that must evaluate as a bool. Does the example I added help?

Comment: What does !<-db.response mean ? If there's nothing on the channel proceed ? But then the read is not blocking - it's like a poll.

Comment: Or does response have to be a bool channel ? And the read blocks until db.response sends something.

Comment: `<-db.response` is a normal receive operation. The `db.response` chan *must* be a `chan bool`, and the `!` is the logical "not" unary operator.